# Series Converges Pointwise but not Uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{n(n+x^2)}$ on $[0,\infty)$. To show pointwise convergence, I used $\frac{x^2}{n(n+x^2)}\leq\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ on $[0,\infty)\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{n(n+x^2)}\leq\sum\frac{x^2}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2 x^2}{6}$.

I'm a little stuck on showing that it doesn't converge uniformly though. I thought that since $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{n(n+x^2)}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$, if $f_n\to f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{n(n+x^2)}$, then $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. To show that this is not the case, I looked at $|f(0)-f(y)|=|y^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+y^2)}|$, but I'm a little stuck on choosing $\epsilon$ smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the series is uniformly convergent on $[0,+\infty[$. Then, if $S(x)$ is the sum of the serie, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $N$, depending only on $\varepsilon$, such that for $n\geq N$ and for all $x\in I=[0,+\infty[$, we have:
 $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k(x)-S(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Choose $m>n\geq N$. We have then for all $x\in I$
 $$|\sum_{k=1}^{n} u_k(x)-S(x)+S(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{m} u_k(x)|=|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} u_k(x)|\leq 2\varepsilon$$
Now we let $x\to +\infty$, and we get that $\displaystyle \sum_{n+1}^{m}\frac{1}{k}\leq 2\varepsilon$, for all $m>n\geq N$. As the harmonic serie is divergent, this is a contradiction.